# Xpath inside xpath

Tags: xpath, xml-parsing, xpath-2.0

I am trying to create an xpath for the below scenario, could you please help ?

How can i find out the value of **C** whose **`@parent`** is *`/A/B/@id`*, that is **PQR**, C may not be the immediate next node . I want to evaluate **result=*/A/B/@id*** and then give the **result** as input to **/A/C[@parent="result"]**..is it possible?

```
<A>
 <B id="1">W</B>
 <C parent="1">PQR</C>
 <C parent="2">ABC</C>
</A>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

With a [predicate filter expression](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-31/#id-filter-expression), you can test whether the `@parent` value of `/A/C` is equal to the `@id` value of the `/A/B` element and it will return the `C` element that satisfies that criteria.

```
/A/C[@parent=/A/B/@id]
```

Comment: Or use `//A/C[@parent=../B/@id]` if you want to make a relative selection (i.e. if there may be more than one `A` involved).